# Como converter um stdClass para array, recursivamente?

Tags: php, array, conversão-de-tipo, stdclass

Tenho o seguinte objeto:

```
$a = new stdClass;
$a->id = 1;
$a->nome = 'wallace';
$a->parentes = new stdClass;

$a->parentes->pai = 'Sidney';
$a->parentes->mae = 'Maria';
```

Sei que com um `cast` é possível converter o `stdClass` para `array`, porém não recursivamente.

Então como posso converter esse objeto para array recursivamente?

Answer (score 1):

Se o objetivo é converter o objeto para array recursivamente, aqui vão algumas dicas.

## Criar uma função

criar uma função para isso:

```
function object_to_array(stdClass $object)
{
    $result = (array)$object;

    foreach($result as &$value) {

        if ($value instanceof stdClass) {
            $value = object_to_array($value);
        }
   }

    return $result;
}
```

## A <del>gambiarra</del> solução do json_encode combinado com json_decode com True no segundo parâmetro

```
json_decode(json_encode($object), true);
```

Comment: Ver também: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16023589

Comment: Essa daí é cabulosa hein, @bfavaretto

Answer (score -3):

Dependendo da versão do PHP você não precisa criar função e nem nada disso, se sua stdClass é apenas do tipo escalar (objetos puros) tu pode simplesmente usar o próprio casting do PHP para fazer isso (apenas versão 7 para cima, em 5.6 não funciona muito bem.

Exemplo:

```
$object = new \StdClass;
$object->id = 12;
$object->name = "TEST"

var_dump((array)$object) // vai printar [ 'id' => 12, 'name' => 'test'];
```

Comment: mas e o stdClass interno? o exemplo não ficou muito claro. Se possível, poste exemplos no ideone.com

Comment: tipo scalar inclui objetos internos, um stdClass não importa quantos objetos internos que você tenha dentro dele desde que sejam scalar, eles virarão array de objetos, para mais referencia eu aconselho a você dá uma estudada na documentação do PHP no php.net.

Comment: Sobre ser escalar, eu sei. A pergunta fala sobre conversão recursiva, que é uma `stdClass` dentro da outra.

Comment: Inclusive a própria pergunta parte da premissa que o cast funciona apenas em um nível, então não vejo essa resposta como respondendo o perguntado, embora não esteja errada,

Comment: A resposta foi adequada paa a pergunta, se tu quisesse em mais níveis era só fazer ela correctamente e de qualquer forma o cast (array) resolve os objetos dentro do próprio criando um array de objectos, na verdade isso está na própria documentação e não é uma argumentação, é só ir lá e ler.

Comment: Jovem, eu acho que você não leu a pergunta direito. A pergunta fala sobre converter um `stdClass` para objeto RECURSIVAMENTE

Comment: Não entendo pq votaram negativo, a resposta funciona muito bem. Inclusive foi a melhor opção no meu caso. Obrigado.

Comment: Deram negativo porque não foram ver a doc / tentaram, inclusive eu tive esse exato problema agora e a solução citada acima funciona até nos dias de hoje (com o 8.2)